# Neo4j spatial search window performance

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial, neo4j-embedded

I am trying to visualise a large amount of spatial graph data, but preliminary results with ~100k nodes/edges aren't looking fast enough for querying and rendering as a user pans around a map.

With the following spatial query on my Neo4j spatially indexed layer (Simple Points Layer) queries are taking around 2-10s.

```
SearchRecords searchRecords = spatialLayer.getIndex().search(new SearchIntersectWindow(spatialLayer, env));


    try (Transaction tx = dbService.beginTx()) {
        for (SpatialDatabaseRecord spatialDatabaseRecord : searchRecords) {
            //do stuff...
        }
        tx.success();
        tx.close();
    }
```

My actual data is more in the order of 50 million nodes/edges. Is there things I can do to get responsive (like sub 1 second) query performance from Neo4j spatial with a large number of nodes/edges?

I am using Neo4j 2.3.0 and Neo4j Spatial 0.15-neo4j-2.2.3

Comment: Disk IO seems to be the bottle neck as data-set size increases. For this use case of displaying a massive graph on a pannable and zoomable map LOD rasterisation is probably the answer.